# Shift Register 74HC595 circuit working weirdly

Tags: shift-register

I built the circuit from the arduino ShiftOut tutorial, but it is not working as expected. I made a simulation model and that one isn't working either.
[image: Simulation I built]

The code I used is from the tutorial:

```
// SH_CP; 11
const int clockPin = 9;
// DS; 15
const int dataPin = 8;
// ST_CP; 12
const int latchPin = 10;

void setup() {
  pinMode(clockPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(dataPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(latchPin, OUTPUT);

  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("reset");
}

void loop() {
  for (int number = 0; number < 256; number++) {
    Serial.println(number);
    digitalWrite(latchPin, LOW);
    shiftOut(dataPin, clockPin, MSBFIRST, number);
    digitalWrite(latchPin, HIGH);
    delay(500);
  }
}
```

Any idea as to what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume that you are referring to [this tutorial](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ShiftOut), and [this code](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ShftOut11).

The `clockPin` of Arduino should be connected to pin 11(SH_CP) of 595, `dataPin` to pin 14(DS), and `latchPin` to pin 12(ST_CP).

Swap the values of `clockPin` and `latchPin` in your code, and you should be good to go.

```
// SH_CP; 11
const int clockPin = 10;
// DS; 14 (not 15)
const int dataPin = 8;
// ST_CP; 12
const int latchPin = 9;
```